# popcorn.js start and stop times

Tags: jquery, media, popcornjs

Just started having a look at popcorn.js but having some trouble.

I've got a 30 second track,

however I'd like the file to start playing from 2 seconds in, and stop playing 3 seconds before the end.

Does anybody know if this is possible as I couldn't find it in the documentation?

Either that or is there a command to jump to a point in the timeline, so almost like

```
pop.playAt('2 second');
```

something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two simple steps here:
1) Advance the video to two seconds in
2) Make sure it stops at 27 seconds (30 - 3)

To advance the video, you can use the currentTime method, but you will run into an error if you try to set currentTime before the video metadata has loaded. (When you first set up a video, the browser doesn't know what the duration is until it gets the header, and you can't set currentTime later than the duration.)

```
var popcorn = Popcorn('#video');
if (popcorn.duration()) {
  popcorn.currentTime(2);
} else {
  popcorn.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
    popcorn.currentTime(2);
  }
}
```

Now, to make sure the video stops at 27 seconds, you can use the "cue" method, which takes a number of seconds and a callback function to fire at that time.

```
popcorn.cue(27, function() {
  popcorn.pause();
});
```

Now, by default, Popcorn fires events when it receives a "timeupdate" event from the video, which is usually every 1/4 second (250ms). So you may see the video run a few frames long. (e.g., it might stop at 27.1 seconds). If you need better accuracy, use the frameAnimation option, which makes popcorn try to update up to 60fps (every 16ms).

```
var popcorn = Popcorn('#video', {
  frameAnimation: true
});
```

You can also save loading time by telling the browser to only ask the web server for the part of the video you need, by appending a hint in the form of an anchor to the URL.

```
http://example.com/videos/myvideo.webm#t=2,27
```

This depends on support from the browser and the web server, but it can't hurt.

**Edit:** Actually, don't use frameAnimation here. The problem is that it uses requestAnimationFrame, and you can't guarantee that it will be called if your browser tab is not visible. It makes sense for animations, but not here. I will probably propose a fix for this in popcorn.js.

Comment: Thanks for this Brian its working to a degree! Our issue now is however as we've got possibly an endless number of players on the page, however lets say we've got 2 players on the page, the 2nd player cannot be interacted with/played unless the first player on the page has had play clicked, so you need to click play on the 1st video before the controls on the 2nd player work, any ideas why this could be happening? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why you need more than one player. Are you trying to play multiple clips consecutively? If you want to share your code, I can take a look and see what else might be off.

Comment: We've got about 30 collapsible divs, that each have a different player in it. We've got 1 50 min audio file, that has cue points, within it. As well as start and stop times. So Div 1, would contain, Between 0s and 30s 21 cue points, Div 2 would contain between 31s and 50s 20 cue points. The issue has been semi-resolved however by using "preload" however now we notice the browser is downloading the mp3, m4a and ogg file, even if it can only support 1 of them, and then it downloads the same file 40 times as there are 40 instances of it on the page! dumb browsers!

Comment: The browser has to retrieve the video header from the server to find out what codec the file uses to see whether it can read that file. Try adding the codec to the source element so the browser can skip that step.  <source src="movie.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />

Comment: For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: @brianchirls, did you had time to work on the problem with non-active tabs? If not, could you give me a hint to know how to start? I might try to put some effort into fixing it.